# How to send traces from rust + tracing_opentelemetry to Honeycomb?

Tags: rust, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, rust-tracing

I've set up a basic subscriber for Rust `tracing` with OpenTelemetry as follows:

```rust
let rust_log = dotenv::var("RUST_LOG").unwrap();
if rust_log == "OTEL" {
    // Use OpenTelemetry subscriber
    let tracer = stdout::new_pipeline().install_simple();
    let telemetry = tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(tracer);
    let otel_subscriber = tracing_subscriber::Registry::default().with(telemetry);
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(otel_subscriber).unwrap();
} else {
    // Revert to what is specified in `RUST_LOG`
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();
}
```

I would now like to change this subscriber to send batched data to Honeycomb. The problem is the official Honeycomb documentation (https://docs.honeycomb.io/getting-data-in/opentelemetry-overview/#using-the-honeycomb-opentelemetry-endpoint) suggests using `opentelemetry-otlp`, which in turn requires running and maintaining a separate "collector service" (https://crates.io/crates/opentelemetry-otlp).

I would like to do this without running a separate collector service. My understanding is that I should be able to directly send logs to Honeycomb without running an intermediary service to do so. Is this viable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust OpenTelemetry OTLP w/ Honeycomb](/q/74281657/2189130)

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko, this other question also introduces a separate connector service so unfortunately it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Really? I was under the impression that the accepted answer doesn't require a collector service.

Comment: You're right! Unfortunately I wasn't able to get that version working either, but will keep trying on all fronts. Feel free to submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it though.

Comment: Got another implementation to work: https://github.com/Dhghomon/rust_opentelemetry_honeycomb.